# Spring Boot + JPA + SQL Server : How Can I Join My Tables(3Tables)

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-boot, join

I use sql-server(sql-server2008) & SpringBoot & JPA
But I don't know that how Can I Join my Three Tables By a their Common Column.

DataBase:

Table1(Article) - ArticleID(PK), TITLE, CONTENTS

Table2(ArticleNowService) - ArticleID, NewsSetID(PK)

Table3(ArticleOldService) - ArticleID, NewsSetID(PK), Seq(PK)

I want to know the same code as the result of this query.

```
SELECT A.ARTICLEID, A.TITLE, A.CONTENTS FROM ARTICLE A INNER JOIN 
ARTICLENOWSERVICE ANS ON A.ARTICLEID = ANS.ARTICLEID WHERE ANS.NEWSSETID = '000'
UNION ALL
SELECT A.ARTICLEID, A.TITLE, A.CONTENTS FROM ARTICLE A INNER JOIN 
ARTICLEOLDSERVICE ANO ON A.ARTICLEID = ANO.ARTICLEID WHERE ANO.NEWSSETID = '000'
```

and this is my current code in Article.java

```
public @Data class Article implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ArticleId id;

 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name = "ArticleID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private java.util.List<ArticleNowService> articleNowService;

 @OneToMany
 @JoinColumn(name = "ArticleID", insertable = false, updatable = false)
 private java.util.List<ArticleOldService> articleOldService;
... @Colums ...
```

ArticleOldService.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ArticleOldService")
public @Data class ArticleOldService implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ArticleOldServiceId id;

@Column(name = "NEWSSETID")
private int newsSetId;
```

ArticleNowService.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "ArticleNowService")
public @Data class ArticleNowService implements java.io.Serializable {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@EmbeddedId
private ArticleNowServiceId id;

@Column(name = "ArticleID")
private String articleId;
```

and then when i use at Repository:

```
@Repository("ArticleDao")
public interface ArticleDao extends JpaRepository<Article, ArticleId> {

List<Article> findAll();
List<Article> findByArticleOldServiceNewsSetId(int newsSetId, Sort sort);
List<Article> findByArticleNowServiceNewsSetId(int newsSetId, Sort sort);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to join in SQL or JPQL?

Comment: suppose you share the `ArticleNowService` and `ArticleOldService` classes as well and it may be helpful.

Comment: added it :) @Rajith Pemabandu

Comment: `private ArticleId id` is there another class called `ArticleId`.

Comment: I doubt there is a issue with your `Entitiy` primary keys. suppose you refer this [example](https://hellokoding.com/jpa-one-to-many-relationship-mapping-example-with-spring-boot-maven-and-mysql/) on Spring Boot JPA. Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a alot @RajithPemabandu